# Why Udev is loading two kernel modules for a single USB device?

Tags: kernel-modules, udev, usb-device

I've a **RTL8153** based USB ethernet adapter, which uses the `cdc_ether` driver by default.

I want to use the `r8152` driver, which could be loaded by creating a custom udev rule, as present in the Realtek's linux driver source.

But here's confusing part, when I plug-in the adapter, both of the `cdc_ether` and `r8152` modules are loaded. My questions are,

1. **Why?**
2. How can I find the udev rule responsible for loading `cdc_ether`?
3. How can I stop loading that module? As it's not necessary to load two modules in this case.

**A line of the Udev rule**

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVER=="r8152", ATTR{idVendor}=="2357", ATTR{idProduct}=="0601", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="$env{REALTEK_NIC_MODE}", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="$env{REALTEK_NIC_MODE}"
```

The `DRIVER==` part is not necessary.

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting?  Check your /etc/modprobe.d for examples.

Comment: No, I don't want to blacklist the module, as it's also used for USB tethering. Thanks !

Comment: Please read 3. carefully: "that module, it's not necessary"

Comment: Yeah, thanks for correcting. Forgot to explicitly mention that it's not necessary in this case, but needed by other devices.

Comment: What is your kernel version? https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/9/25/711

Comment: Great tip! Just wow! I'm using kernel 4.10.10 custom compiled, I'll implement the patch in 4.14 series.

Comment: Let me know if I may put it as an answer.

Comment: That should be fine. I'm also looking for some more answers.

Comment: Better take the 4.15 asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVER=="r8152", ATTR{idVendor}=="2357", ATTR{idProduct}=="0601", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="$env{REALTEK_NIC_MODE}", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="$env{REALTEK_NIC_MODE}"
```

The meaning of this udev rule is as follows:
"When a device with `idVendor` value 2357 and `idProduct` value 0601 (and managed by driver "r8152") is added to the system, if its `bConfigurationValue` is not whatever value is defined in environment variable `REALTEK_NIC_MODE`, set its `bConfigurationValue`to that value."

In other words, this udev rule is not loading the r8152 driver, it's switching the device to the correct mode for that driver if necessary.

When a new device is added, Linux kernel basically runs `modprobe` with the hardware IDs (and some other things) of the device encoded in the "name" of the module it requests. This "name" is then compared by `modprobe` to wildcard strings embedded into each module as module aliases. The `depmod` command gathers up these alias names and stores them into `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/modules.alias[.bin]` for quick searching. You can view the alias strings embedded into kernel modules with the `modinfo` command.

For your USB ethernet adapter, the "name" is something like `usb:v2357p0601d...`. Unfortunately, the `cdc_ether` module has a wildcard alias that will match it too.

Any aliases defined in `/etc/modprobe.d` will take precedence over aliases embedded into modules themselves. So, you could probably specify an alias that will match your ethernet adapter and causes the `r8152` module to be loaded instead.

Try adding this as `/etc/modprobe.d/usbnic.conf`:

```
alias usb:v2357p0601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8152
```

Then run `depmod -a` as root, unplug the USB ethernet adapter, unload both the `r8152` and `cdc_ether` modules, plug the ethernet adapter back in and see what happens. If only the r8152 module is loaded, good.

If the `cdc_ether` still gets loaded too, the alias might need to be more specific (i.e. one or more of the asterisks in it needs to be replaced with actual values, whatever they might be) in order for this alias to be the most specific and thus the "best" match.

Update: 
Here is a description of the module alias format: http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, perfect solution. But I have a question, how did you calculated the wildcard alias?

Comment: If you do a `modinfo <any USB device driver>` you'll see one or more examples. The first two elements are pretty obviously `v`endor and `p`roduct IDs, and the rest is just following the format and replacing any other variables with wildcards. Full description here: http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a patch for this problem in recent kernels: https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/9/25/711

Comment: That patch does not seem to match the vendor&product IDs of the original poster's device, so I'm afraid it would have no effect. But it would be a great model for making a similar patch for the OP's device.